# How to get data from two services with an ID and display the content

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, service, controller

In PHP you could say `SELECT "message" FROM "users" WHERE id = $id` But how do can I select in AngularJS (JavaScript) like the PHP way.

Here are my services at the moment:

```
app.service("users", function() {
    this.userList = [
        {
            userId: 1,
            username: "John",
            password: "Doe"
        },
        {
            userId: 2,
            username: "Jane",
            password: "Doe"
        }
    ];
    this.text = function() {
        return "Hello";
    };
});

app.service("userMessages", function() {
    this.messages = [
        {
            userId: 1,
            message: [
                {
                    text: "This is a message from user 1"
                },
                {
                    text: "This is another message from user 1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            userId: 2,
            message: [
                {
                    text: "This is a message from user 2"
                },
                {
                    text: "This is another message from user 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

And my controller is like this:

```
app.controller("controller", function($scope, users, userMessages) {
    $scope.users = users.userList;

    var id = $scope.users.length

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.users.push(
            {
                userId: ++id,
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            }
        );
        $scope.username = "";
        $scope.password = "";
    };
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        {{ user.userId }}<br />
        {{ user.username }}<br />
        {{ user.password }}<br />
        <hr />
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username"><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password"><br />
    <button ng-click="add()">Add user</button>
</div>
```

This is a simple test that I made to see how I could display the messages from the `userMessages` service and link them to the users in the `users` service.

I have no idea how to do this.

I have done some research but I could not find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your question how to interact with a database? If so use ajax.

Comment: @Daan Not with a database. My question is how can I get the messages (userMessages service) for the users (users service). I do not use a database. I don't know how to get each message that the user has typed and display them next to the name of the user because the data is in two services.

Comment: So you're talking about how to parse data from a javascript array?

Comment: @BenBlack Yes. I want to get the data from the two services from the `userId` and display the messages from the users next the their name.

Comment: I think you're looking for `indexOf()`

Comment: @Daan So with `indexOf()` I could specify the `userId` and display the messages form the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if to compare the `users.userId and messages.userId` and display them according to the user

Here is the working plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/39Dd6AtKorcxX24fNmJF/preview

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some data to show you how you can use javascripts `Array.prototype.filter` to grab data from arrays based on a parameter.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('users', function() {
    this.userList = [{
      userId: 1,
      username: "John",
      password: "Doe"
    }, {
      userId: 2,
      username: "Jane",
      password: "Doe"
    }];
    this.text = function() {
      return "Hello";
    };
  })
  .service('userMessages', function() {
    var messages = [{
      userId: 1,
      messages: [{
        text: "This is a message from user 1"
      }, {
        text: "This is another message from user 1"
      }]
    }, {
      userId: 2,
      messages: [{
        text: "This is a message from user 2"
      }, {
        text: "This is another message from user 2"
      }]
    }];

    this.getUsersMessages = function(id) {
      return messages.filter(function(obj, i) {
        return obj.userId == id;
      });
    }
  })
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'users', 'userMessages',
    function($scope, users, userMessages) {
      $scope.user1 = users.userList[0];
      $scope.user2 = users.userList[1];
      
      $scope.user1Messages = userMessages.getUsersMessages($scope.user1.userId);
      $scope.user2Messages = userMessages.getUsersMessages($scope.user2.userId);
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{user1Messages}}
    <br />
    {{user2Messages}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM * WHERE` has nothing to do with PHP, it's SQL language of a database, like MySQL.

When you want to make queries to javascript array consider using methods of [javascript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).